# CDHtmlDialog - make it modal?

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, modal-dialog

I am popping up a `CDHtmlDialog` box when user clicks inside a another dialog box. Here is the pseudo code

```
CMyClass{
    CDHtmlDialog * m_htmlDialog;
}

CMyClass::OnInitDialog(){
     m_htmlDialog = new CDHtmlDialog(IDD_DIALOG_EMAIL, IDR_HTML_SUBMIT_EMAIL);
}

CMyClass::OnBnClickSendEmail{

     m_htmlDialog->Create(IDD_DIALOG_EMAIL);
     //m_htmlDialog->DoModal();
     m_htmlDialog->ShowWindow(SW_SHOWNORMAL);
}
```

The code runs fine when the `DoModal` is commented. But the problem is that the Html Dialog is not modal and I can click on the background forms and dialogs. I want the Html dialog to be modal and when I uncomment the `DoModal()` line the code crashes.

Comment: _"the code crashes"_ -- Does it really crash or is an assertion triggered? Run a debug build of your program and press the "retry" button in the dialog where Visual Studio tells you about the "crash". This should show you the location in code, where the "crash" actually happens.

Comment: yeah i am running in debugger and the code crashes on the DoModal line in debug mode.

Comment: It does not crash. It displays a dialog. Why are you refusing to read it?

Comment: @IInspectable sorry can you please clarify what i am refusing to read? I meant that the program crashes in the debug mode .. there is an exception from the mfc library when domodal is called.

Comment: The MFC dialog code does not use exceptions. If there is an exception, then that is an operating system exception (SEH), one you can instruct the debugger to break when raised. If this does indeed terminate the process due to an unhandled SEH exception, then you are doing something fishy (like calling the code on a non-GUI thread).

Comment: have you traced into the call to see why it crashes.

Comment: Also, why are you "creating" it? If you want it as modal, you have already created it in `OnInitDialog`. So just use `DoModal` and nothign else.

Comment: I realize now the problem, the parent window is modalless and child window of a modalless window cannot call DoModal().

Comment: @Andrew let me try that too

Comment: Well, it would be modal, relative to that parent only in that case.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle  thats exactly what i want, modal to the the modalless parent. If you have an answer please write it

Comment: Potentially you could make the parent the actual master app which is modal. Depends on your program situation.

Comment: No, this is wrong. Modality has nothing to do with child/parent relationships. You do need to set an owner window, though. Otherwise using a modal dialog has no effect over not using a modal dialog. Reading [window features](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599.aspx) is highly recommended. Not using MFC is also highly recommended, when you're struggling with the Windows API.

Comment: @IInspectable thank you for the link, i will read up. Can't help using mfc ... legacy code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I display a modal dialog, when it begins as a `null` pointer:

```
auto *pDlgEditor = new CSomeDlg(this);
if (pDlgEditor != nullptr)
{
    pDlgEditor->DoModal();

    delete pDlgEditor;
}
```

Notice that I am passing `this` which is the owner for the window.

The actual class itself specifies the dialogue resource:

```
CSomeDlg::CChristianLifeMinistryEditorDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialogEx(IDD_DIALOG_EXAMPLE, pParent))
```

I realise that my code doesn't show a `CDHtmlDialog` ... According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/mfc/reference/cdhtmldialog-class#cdhtmldialog) there are 3 constructors:

> ```
> CDHtmlDialog();
>
>
> CDHtmlDialog(
>     LPCTSTR lpszTemplateName,  
>     LPCTSTR szHtmlResID,  
>     CWnd *pParentWnd = NULL);
>
>
> CDHtmlDialog(
>     UINT nIDTemplate,  
>     UINT nHtmlResID = 0,  
>     CWnd *pParentWnd = NULL);
> ```

The third parameter is the parent which defaults to `NULL`. Try passing `this` as the third parameter.

Now, if you are **inside** a popup **modaless** window when you do the above the parent will be the modaless window. But if you pass the modaless windows' **parent** then **that** will become the owner instead. We don't have full information so the above is just generic advice.

---

Note that the documentation states that if you leave the `pParentWnd` as the default (`NULL`):

> If it is `NULL`, the dialog object's parent window is set to the main application window.

So, it might not necessarily use the parent you expect, which is why it is good to specify it yourself.

Comment: thank you!! this is working for me. I realize this must be basic stuff, i am still learning MFC and documentation is not very clear to me.

Comment: I am glad it helped. I added a little more information to my answer for you.

Comment: In your example `new CSomeDlg(this)` is pointless, as you can just do `CSomeDlg dlg(this); dlg.DoModal();` or even `CSomeDlg(this).DoModal()` and avoid the potential memory leak. In modern C++ there is no need for `delete` and only rarely a need for `new`.

Comment: @zett42 I showed that for two reasons. 1. In his example he was using a pointer. 2. When I use code analysis sometimes it flags up on the size of my dialogue and to handle it the suggestion was to declare it as a pointer. So under normal circumstances I don't use it unless I have to.

Comment: You still don't have to use raw pointers, use one that manages the memory, like `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: @zett42 Well, I would have, if I knew about it. :) Programming is essentially a hobby for me. My official training was back in the days of `Visual C++ 6.0` and everything I know today is what I pick up. I will investigate the pointer class you refer to. Thanks.